# Server Selection Timeout Error, MongoDB Change Streams

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to test insert into Mongo Change stream with the following code. Only these 2lines

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STR)
print(client.changestream.collection.insert_one({"hello": "world"}).inserted_id)
```

The error I'm getting when I run this python file is as follow,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(client.changestream.collection.insert_one({"hello": "world"}).inserted_id)
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 697, in insert_one
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1611, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1598, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1551, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1584, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 431, in get_server_session
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "D:\PyMongo Change Streams\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 199, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats,PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats,PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats
```

I've also test the connection with the following code, and it's working well and print out db info.

```
# try:
#     client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STR)
#     db = client.API
#     print(db)
# except Exception as e:
#     print(e)
```

Can anyone please help me explain about this error?

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats,PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats,PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats
```

It's my very first time working with MongoDB changestream. Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just check the packages' versions and fixed this.

Comment: Hi! How did you fixed it? Did you change/upgrade some package version?